# My TensorFlow code produces an error with the dimensionality of inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InvalidArgumentError: Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4, not [32,32,28,28]
     [[Node: Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild = ImageSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, bad_color=Tensor<type: uint8 shape: [4] values: 255 0 0...>, max_images=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild/tag, Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild/tensor/_39)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-73b3b51081a0> in <module>()
     18             print(i, 'Trainingsgenauigkeit = ', genau*100,'%', 'verlust = ', verlust)
     19 
---> 20             s = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y, dropoutPH:dropout})
     21             writer.add_summary(s, i)
     22     genauigkeitTest = sess.run(genauigkeitTraining, feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels, keep_prob:1.0})

C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4, not [32,32,28,28]
     [[Node: Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild = ImageSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, bad_color=Tensor<type: uint8 shape: [4] values: 255 0 0...>, max_images=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild/tag, Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild/tensor/_39)]]

Caused by op 'Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild', defined at:
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 127, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1425, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 127, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 759, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 536, in <lambda>
    self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda : self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2901, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-9e8915c7d2a2>", line 26, in <module>
    tf.summary.image('Konvolution1Bild', tf.unstack(konv1, axis = 3))
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py", line 162, in image
    tag=tag, tensor=tensor, max_images=max_outputs, name=scope)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py", line 387, in image_summary
    bad_color=bad_color, name=name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\Matura\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4, not [32,32,28,28]
     [[Node: Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild = ImageSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, bad_color=Tensor<type: uint8 shape: [4] values: 255 0 0...>, max_images=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild/tag, Konvolution1/Konvolution1Bild/tensor/_39)]]
```

Snippets of the code that produce this error:

```
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    writer= tf.summary.FileWriter( "/tmp/mnist_logs", sess.graph)

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(anzahlIterationen):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batchGrösse)

        sess.run(training, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, dropoutPH:dropout})

        if i % (np.floor(anzahlIterationen/5)) == 0:
            verlust, genau = sess.run([kreuzentropie, genauigkeitTraining], feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y, dropoutPH:dropout})
            print(i, 'Trainingsgenauigkeit = ', genau*100,'%', 'verlust = ', verlust)

            s = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y, dropoutPH:dropout})
            writer.add_summary(s, i)
    genauigkeitTest = sess.run(genauigkeitTraining, feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels, keep_prob:1.0})
    print("test accuracy %g"%(testAccurac
```

I really don't know where this error comes from. I can't think of a way to influence the tensors that I input because I want data from that.

The code already worked for previous versions. I can't think of I moment where I changed something with the summary

Comment: It appears that the input to your image summary in the first convolutional layer has 28 channels (i.e. the 4th dimension is 28 in size). Obviously it is unclear how to generate an image out of this (as stated in the error message, the allowed number of channels is either 1, 3 or 4).

Comment: Oh, I just no realized what I changed: I wanted to make my biases visible and screwed up there. Know I know where the problem is at least.